# How can I see my player movements in Counter Strike?

Tags: pc, counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike, counter-strike-source

I am new in Counter Strike. I have one laptop where I am practising my movement skills playing alone. I would like to see my player so I can understand the movement mechanics for when I am going to be playing online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `CS 1.6` and `CS:S` you can just use the following console commands(as in this video:

)

Step by step what they say there:

- Open console
- Type: `sv_cheats 1`
- Type: `thirdperson`

That's it. There are 3 commands that they also use:

- `cam_idealdist`
- `cam_idealyaw`
- `cam_idealpitch`

From the video I'd say that the best would be to set `cam_idealyaw` and `cam_idealpitch` to 0 and `cam_idealdist` to 50 or 100 or whatever you like the most.

***CS:GO***

The only thing that I found for it were some youtube comments. They recommend setting both `sv_cheats` and `Cam_Command` to `1`. But it seems to be extremely buggy.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your answer...i have a counter strike 1.6 but it isn't working ...

Comment: thanksssssssssss it works.. actually i know what i was doing wrong ... i have to enable this cheat at the start of the game instead of while playing ... thank you ... god bless you ..

Comment: @irfan you can enable `sv_cheats` while gaming, but don't forget to restart the game after it(`restart` or `sv_restart` or `sv_restartround`)

Comment: I never understood why Valve made the `thirdperson` require `sv_cheats 1`. It's not like looking at your character in third person view is cheating, or is it?

Comment: @Nolonar viewing from third person view may give you a big unfair advantage at the corners imho

Comment: @Nolonar As Novarg said, while on a corner, using third person would allow you to "corner-check" without being visible/targettable.