# cross-hair problem when viewing as a third person

Tags: counter-strike

I have followed [this solution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115065/how-can-i-see-my-player-movements-in-counter-strike) so I can play in 3rd person view.

Now the problem is that my crosshair is showing at the back of the player not in front of the gun or player, how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: `A picture is worth a thousand words` - screenshot please

Comment: *my crosshair is showing at the back of the player*  So basically you are trying to sgoot yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If what you are saying is accurate - the camera has basically just been pulled back and the third person player model made visible in place of the first person one. in which case, you'd be seeing your head as that is in the dead center of where the camera comes from.

This means the crosshair is lined up properly, but that it is obstructed by the player model. This can only be fixed by using the console to adjust the camera position in third person, but this WILL screw up the crosshair alignment (meaning shots will not land directly on the crosshair any more)

The commands to fix this, while i dont remember them off the top of my head, should be either start with "cl_camera" or just "camera".

Hope this helps